# add youtube thumbnail in index and single.php add video

Tags: thumbnails, embed, youtube

I crating custom wordpress themes for video related website, client can embed youtube video,
in index.php only show thumbnail image and title of video then when click thumbnail it goes to single.php & show the video,

Plase any one help me,
I try [Video Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/video-thumbnails/) it not work me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this:

**`1.`** Add [custom meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to each post which take [youtube url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api)( name of custom meta in code youtube).

**`2.`** In `index.php` loop:

```
  while(have_posts()){

    the_post();

   //use [get_post_meta][3] to get youtube post meta
   $youtube_img = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.substr( get_post_meta($post-ID,'youtube') ).'/0.jpg';

   //$youtube_img is your youtube video image url
   echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
   echo '<img src="'.$youtube_img.'" title="'.get_the_title().'" alt="youtube video image for'.get_the_title().'"/>';
   echo'</a>';
   }
```

**`3.`** In `single.php` loop (set iframe width as you design need)

```
<?php
while(have_posts()){
    the_post();

    //use [get_post_meta][3] to get youtube post meta
    $youtube_link = get_post_meta($post-ID,'youtube');   
    ?>    

    //$youtube_link is your youtube url
    <iframe width="328" height="233" src="<?php echo str_replace('watch?v=','embed/', $youtube_link); ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    <?php
}
```

Comment: This my code all so not working     <?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()){

 the_post();

   //use [get_post_meta][3] to get youtube post meta
   $youtube_img = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.substr( get_post_meta($post-ID,'youtube') ).'/0.jpg';

   //$youtube_img is your youtube video image url
   echo '<a href="'get_permalink().'">';
   echo '<img src="'.$youtube_img.'" title="'.get_the_title().'" alt="youtube video image for'.get_the_title().'"/>';
   echo'</a>;'
   }
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

Comment: their are some error in php code formatting in your code. Try this `<?php 
if (have_posts()) : 
 while(have_posts()){ 
  the_post(); 
  //use [get_post_meta][3] to get youtube post meta 
  $youtube_img = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.substr( get_post_meta($post-ID,'youtube') ).'/0.jpg'; 
  //$youtube_img is your youtube video image url 
  echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
  echo '<img src="'.$youtube_img.'" title="'.get_the_title().'" alt="youtube video image for'.get_the_title().'"/>';
  echo'</a>';
 } 
 endif;
?>`